# Writing data into jasmine framework?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am using default framework of jasmine with Protractor. It's all about related to screenshot/HTML Final status reporting.

But I want to write data on HTML report like writing data in console using `console.log("Username Entered"+Username).`

I want the method like `test_Step_Info("Username Entered"+Username)` that should be printed given data into HTML report.

And also need the overall code that should be pasted in index JavaScript file of jasmine framework (HTML Binding with methods).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Show your code for example.